# Can I use my laptop as router in the bridge mode?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, internet

In the dormitory I have only ethernet and very low wifi signal. To connect to internet all MAC addresses should be registered to the system. To share wifi they told me I have to use a router in bridge mode and to not create another network.

I think if I connect ethernet to laptop and use hotspot to share internet to my tablet and phone it creates another network and they block it (sometimes internet works sometimes not).

So is any way to use hotspot from laptop as bridge and connect my tablet and mobile phone without buying a router?

Comment: What OS?.   Google "Internet connection sharing" if you are using Windows.

Comment: I already searched many things about ICS. I want to take Internet from ethernet and to share it with wifi, not the opposite. If I use mobile hotspot in windows 10 it creates a subnetwork that is not accepted. I want to bridge it.

Comment: Are you set on only using Windows to try and accomplish this?

Comment: And if you are not set on Windows, it's easy in Linux: Use `hostapd` to create a WLAN AP, bridge WLAN network interface with LAN interface, done.

Comment: Yes I want only in windows. Connectify application has an option to share as bridge but says it may not work, and it is not working.

Comment: Ok. So I’m not sure why they are telling you what they are. But I’m going to share a secret with you. Plug a standard WiFi router in to that Ethernet port and get the MAC address of the router authorized. Your school network has NO idea what is behind the router and it would be impossible for them to block anything other than everything or nothing. They are telling you not to do exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: @appleoddity, they may be using port-security. In that case you would want to try and Mac clone the "authorized" device **before** plugging it in. Some schools do this because they already have a "honey-combed" wireless network established, and don't want to deal with the interference from personal routers.

Comment: Tim_Stewart: From OP's question it seems like they already allow network extensions, they just want them to be configured in a specific way. They're most likely requesting bridge mode because they want to know which student should be responsible for unusual traffic, abuse reports and such. (On top of that, bridge mode allows transparent roaming between identically-named APs.) @Appleoddity's method technically works, but (obviously) makes it seem as if all traffic is linked to OP's account – which is probably not wise if they plan on sharing the AP with everyone around.

Comment: @Appleoddity: When people come here and ask how to bypass university/company security measures, it usually gets closed and someone tells them to go and ask their local IT first. Here the OP is actually trying to cooperate with IT, so why now suggest the opposite?